# How to create an instance of a Java class in Processing?

Tags: java, class, processing, libraries

I'm trying to build a custom Processing library (Java) for data visualization, in Eclipse, named `dataviz.library`. AND I'm a n00b.
I'd like to have a main class in the library, called `Algorithms`, and another subordinate class named `Frame` with has to be constructed with two parameters (floats, x and y). I'd like to be able to call `Frame` like this:

```
import dataviz.library.*;

Algorithms Alg;

void setup() {
  Alg = new Algorithms(this);
  float x = 0;
  float y = 0;
  Frame F = new Alg.Frame(x, y);
}
```

Now, I can access all the methods in the `Algorithms` class but I don't understand how to set up my `Frame` class in Eclipse to be able to access it. Frame should be a method in the `Algorithms` class? But can a method be a class constructor? I'm very confused. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a `newFrame(float x, float y)` method in **Algorithms**, which calls the constructor for the **Frame** class? You could then create a new `Frame` by calling `Alg.newFrame(x, y);`

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to keep Algorithms tidy and clean and have other methods as separate classes in other Java files...if it makes sense!